# How a device driver recognise the peripheral mapping in embedded unix

Tags: linux, embedded, driver, hardware, embedded-linux

In most example project for embedded system there is a `system` file in which we can find structures for different peripheral as well as the memory mapping of the peripheral register, in addition there is also a module per peripheral that contains basic function to manipulate the periheral like: `periph_enable`, `periph_write`, `periph_read`; this is the architecture i have in mind when i tackle a new project.

Actually i started to work with a BF609 but now with an embedded linux in it, my task consist in writing a communication driver with another device via UART, as usual i tried to look for the files i used to use but in vain, i can't find the mapping of the different peripheral.

I started to read [this book](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/linuxdrive3/book/), i undrestand that the kernel see each device like a file and that a driver is mainly the implementation of the `open`, `close`, `read` and `write`functions in these file but i still don't undrestand how these functions communicate with peripheral registers.

My questions:

1) How device drivers recognise the mapping of the peripheral is there sth i missed, is there any example that explain how to implement simple `read` and `write` functions via UART for example

2) Where can i find the mapping of the peripheral in the buildroot directory

Thanks in advance

Comment: a uart is a serial device, so the notion of using reads and writes makes a lot of sense, write some bytes and they will be sent serially.  out the driver buffers incoming, when your read, you get some of them.   beyond that it is just how unix does things trying to treat everything as a file.  the operating system traps the reads and writes and directs them at the driver which buffers the data up in each direction and as the peripheral is ready sends or receives.  the uart being the cleanest example.

Comment: @dwelch, thanks for your feedback, yes i see the purpose of using files,  howver my question is how the kernel recognize for example that the data register of the uart peripheral is in the address 0xaaaaaa, in which file i can find the register mapping of the peripheral for my device ?

Comment: the kernel knows the file system and by filename it then associates a handle and then accesses to that handle go to a particular driver.   the driver knows from the architecture of the system where the uart is.  for x86 it is simply in a known place even if that is a virtual deal.  that and there are usb based ones so when it enumerates the usb it finds it and when it enumerates well walks the pcie tree as the bios enumerates that it finds more.  nothing special about the uart, every device is somewhere and discovered and then the driver is told where and just remembers in data structures.

Comment: for system on a chip then you simply read the manual for the chip, and either hard code the driver or have the device tree get hardcoded for that chip and the driver is generic and pulls the address from the device tree.

Comment: so when the driver is started it already knows because it is compiled in, or it gets info from a table like the device tree or atags, or a config file, etc.  there isnt and doesnt need to be one universal answer.

Comment: If you are using open(), read(), write() type calls, you are probably not writing a kernel driver, but rather writing a userspace driver, interface library, or application which uses an existing kernel driver.  It is the job of *that* driver to implement these generic operations against the hardware details - be they compiled in, passed at driver load, read from device tree, or some other method on the particular system in question.

Comment: @ Chris Stratton, yes that's it i have to implement a user space API that calls the UART driver. the problem is that i even don't know where the UART driver is located, so what are the header file i should include ? and what are the functions i can call from the driver?

Comment: @dwelch i start to get the point, you mean i have to use the filename associated with the UART and then the kernel will call the good driver, the question is from where i get the list of all the filenames ?

Comment: The userspace API to a UART driver is the serial api.  It is not specific to the given driver.  Do a web search for examples of talking to a serial port on  Linux in C or whatever you want to use.

Comment: you can use ls /dev  or find /dev to see them or search the source code for linux drivers to see the possibilities.  when you "open" /dev/ttyS0 there is a uart kernel driver registered for that device (filename), and the kernel via system calls associated with that filename send those read/write open/close requests to the driver.  the driver then depending on the peripheral does stuff, uart, being the most obvious.  there is no magic here, pretty straight forward.